# In Elixir, how do I remove ALL whitespace from a string?

Tags: join, split, trim, sigils

I want to remove ALL whitespace from a string, that is, if I have:
`rna= "AUG UUU UCU" Then I'd like to have:` new_rna="AUGUUUUCU"

How do I do that in Elixir?`

I looked up way of trimming strings but that hardly helps for whitespace in the interior of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.replace/4` for replacing white space with no space.

```
String.replace("AUG UUU UCU", " ", "")
```